# Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am making a website using Next.js and the above error is shown every time.

Don't know what is wrong in my code.

```
const Login = () => {
  const [userMsg, setUserMsg] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const router=useRouter();

  const handleOnChangeEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserMsg("");
    console.log("event", e);
    const email = e.target.value;
    setEmail(email);
  };
  const handleLoginWithEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (email) {
      if (IsEmail.validate(email)){
        router.push("/")
        
      }else{
        setUserMsg("Enter a valid email address")
      }
      
    } else {
      //show usermssg
      setUserMsg("Enter an email address");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="bg-[url('/static/bglg.jpg')] flex items-stretch flex-col h-screen w-full">
      <head>
        <title>NeoVest SignIn</title>
      </head>
      <header className="text-4xl px-10 py-2 font-black">
        <span className="text-indigo-700">NeoVest</span>
      </header>
      <div className="w-full max-w-xs m-auto bg-[#C9C9C9] rounded p-5 bg-opacity-50 border-gray-200">
        <header>
          <div className="text-indigo-700 font-black text-3xl py-2">
            <p>Sign In</p>
          </div>
        </header>
        <form className="py-5">
          <div>
            <label className="block mb-2 text-indigo-500" for="username">
              Email
            </label>
            <input
              className="w-full p-2 mb-6 text-indigo-700 border-b-2 border-indigo-500 outline-none focus:bg-gray-300"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              placeholder="Email Address"
              onChange={handleOnChangeEmail}
            />
            <div className="block mb-2 text-red-700">
              <p>{userMsg}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              className="w-full bg-indigo-700 hover:bg-pink-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 mb-6 rounded"
              type="button"
              value="Submit"
              onClick={handleLoginWithEmail}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Another error shown is due to some suspense boundary causing root to switch to client side rendering :

> Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened
> outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client
> rendering.

I am also using Tailwind if that information is important.

Comment: Are you certain this is the component triggering the error? This code by itself doesn't seem to have anything that would cause the hydration error.

Comment: @juliomalves the error is only being shown on this page so idk what else could be a problem. If you have any idea ill look at that file. My project is based on "npx create-next-app"

Comment: Also e.preventDefault() is also not helping prevent reloading on enter

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you would look at the console you would see a warning.

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <head> cannot appear as a child of <div>
```

So, to fix this you just have to move head out of the div and move it to a different higher component.

Comment: Thanks, worked just fine my error was because I put <a> inside <NextLink>

Comment: That was exactly my case too. This happened to me after I upgraded next.js from major version 12 to 13. You can use nextjs codemods to do this automagically. Reference. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/codemods#new-link

Comment: Thanks a lot, In my case I was wrapping the body in the <Provider> of redux, by keeping <Provider> within body the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @codeoholic I'm using framer-motion's motion wrapping my section for animation, that section does happen to have form. How do I work around this problem without having to change my requirement?

Answer (score 3):

if you have this Warning in chrome:

> validateDOMNesting(...): `<head>` cannot appear as a child of `<div>`

Your DOM Tree is not printed in the browser correctly, one or more tags are not closed properly.

Comment: Yup, look for improperly closed tags generated by React components. <form> and <head> are likely culprits.

Should be top answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
<head>
    <title>NeoVest SignIn</title>
</head>
```

To solve it, first import Head, and then, use it with Capital "H"

```
import Head from "next/head"

<Head>
    <title>NeoVest SignIn</title>
</Head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Time and randomness are two of the things that most commonly produce this.

As discussed in [Hydration errors - Text content does not match server-rendered HTML](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38263), a possible solution might be to use the `useEffect` hook.

```
const AllNames = ["Ali", "Elisa", "Bella", "Carmen"];

export default function ModernNames(){
    const [randomNames, setRandomNames] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const randomUniqueNames = Array.from({ length: 4 })
            .map((_, index) => {
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * AllNames.length);
                let name = AllNames[randomIndex];
                return { name };
            });

        setRandomNames(randomUniqueNames);
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>ModernNames</h1>
            { randomNames.map((name, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{name.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case , the "There was an error while hydrating. ..." is come from when i try to add Toaster in react-hot-toast or ToastContainer in react-toastify into layout.tsx, i removed it and set this toast into any component need to use, hope it helpful

Answer (score 0):

I verified some topics in my code.

First, verify if `styled-components` was declared in `next.config.js`.

```
reactStrictMode: true,
compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
},
```

Second, I checked if `.babelrc` was created in the root folder with this content:

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": ["styled-components"]
}
```

The error still showed.

Component by component, I checked, and two more errors were found. First, HTML errors like this:

```
<!-- wrong -->
<p>
    <ul></ul>
</p>

<!-- right -->
<p></p>
    <ul></ul>
<p></p>

<!-- or right -->
<div>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Finally, I found an error in initializing my component. In my case, I declared - incorrectly - a `const items` (object). The right way to execute this is using `useState`:

```
<!-- WRONG WAY THAT I WAS DID -->
const Works = () => {
  const items =  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'any name',
      src: 'srcpath'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'any name 2',
      src: 'srcpath'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'any name 3',
      src: 'srcpath'
    },
];

return(
   items.map((item, index) => {
     return(
        <div key={index}>{item.name}</div>
     )
   }
)
});

<!-- RIGHT WAY THAT I FIXED -->
const Works = () => {
  const [ item, setItem ] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
     setItem([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'any name',
      src: 'srcpath'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'any name 2',
      src: 'srcpath'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'any name 3',
      src: 'srcpath'
    },
   ]);
  }, []);
  
if(item)
return(
   items.map((item, index) => {
     return(
        <div key={index}>{item.name}</div>
     )
   }
)
});
```

Comment: Why is the first way wrong? If the data is static, I don't understand what the problem would be.

Comment: Because you do not can put ul inside p. It's not good practice. And in the React gives trouble

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this issue when in my layout.tsx file I put my Footer component outside of  tag.

As my stacktrace didn't tell me anything, I started commenting out the components starting with the layout.tsx file to find the error. Maybe it is worth to mention that I'm using Next13 and Turbopack.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a very novice mistake and I was trying to solve it for hours on end. Remember that **`{childern}` go inside `<body>` tag along with your `<Header>` and `<Footer>` components**. example:

This will generate this error (Alongside many more): 
**layout.tsx**

```
<html lang="en">
        <Header /> //Header outside of the body
        <body className={inter.className}>
          {children}
        </body>
        <Footer/> //Footer outside of the body
</html>
```

Change it to this:

```
<html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Footer/>
        </body>
        
</html>
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had was just replacing the root `div` for `main`

### Instead of

```
function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

### Use main tag

```
function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Login page</h1>
    </main>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by disabling ssr when importing the component that gives the hydration warning

```js
///Libraries -->
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Testimony = dynamic(() => import("@/components/testimony/Testimony"), { ssr: false })

/**
 * @title Homepage
 */
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Testimony />
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -12):

You can try downgrading react version. Try react@17.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).